# OData Connection String for "Active Directory Password" Authentication?

Tags: odata, connection-string

Using OData's DataServiceQuery, what should the connection string be like for a server using "Active Directory Password" authentication. I have been using this pattern for the connection string:

> {https://services.xxx.com/services.svc/Devices()?$filter=MAC eq 'AQAyHwIAr98DAOpRBACdvwUAsm4HAGpmCAAshAkARL9%3D'&?UID={admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com}&?PWD={xxxxxxxx}}

However, I am getting this error returned:

> Either Credential or both 'User ID' and 'Password' (or 'UID' and 'PWD') connection string keywords must be specified, if 'Authentication=Active Directory Password'.

I have used numerous variants for the "user id" and "password" options as well as used/not used "?" for the option names and braces for the values to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you add the credentials via the NetworkCredential method to the context of the message, i.e.:

```
// Set context for Data Service
target_context = new targetDBmodel.targetDBtables(svcUri);
target_context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user name", "password", "domain");
```